# Try to set up IMAP (Javamail)

Tags: java, email, smtp

Basically i've written up a SMTP server in Java and it works great. I have a website which gets user input (From: , To: , Subject, Body) outputs it into a log file then Java reads that and sends the email. If someone tries replying, i want it to get forwarded to their personal email (gmail, yahoo, hotmail, etc...). Any idea on the best way of doing this?

Comment: You could add an auto-generated message ID in the header of every e-mail. If you have a mail client (i.e. Outlook) you can look up how to big provider implements their "message history".

Comment: Like post the actual return address? I don't want to it be like that. I want it to be where all receiver needs to do is reply to the email and it forwards to whichever email the user entered.

Comment: I tried to elaborate in my answer. You must set an "hidden" ID to re-recognize the e-mail.

Comment: I'm just trying to get it so i can have the email forwarded somewhere at this point, then i can figure the rest out

Answer (score 0):

My answer bases on this webpage here: http://www.avolio.com/columns/E-mailheaders.html in conjunction with this wiki entry (Message ID) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-ID

I suggest that you add an message-id (i.e [java.util.UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html))every time an e-mail is sent. This ID you must also store in a database. If you receive an answer, you can look up to whom you should forward it.

The large providers also use these Message-IDs to create the history of the conversation.

Keep me posted if you wish further details.

Comment: See, my problem is just getting started. When i reply to one of my emails i get a postmaster error.